# Why is MediaRecorder.prepare() throwing an IOException?

Tags: android, mobile-development

I am just trying to make a simple video recording app. I have spent days trying to figure this error out and I have had no luck. I am so close to just deleting my whole computer, this error is driving me mad! I followed developer.android.com and YouTube tutorials. I can't see why my code doesn't work as I copied everything they did.

http://pastebin.com/q84v81hG

I put all the code in a paste bin because the code messes up when I put it here.

Thanks for any help!

BTW I am aware I haven't added a button that stops recording, I am just trying to get it recording in the first place before I add that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: I have been using android 5.0 so that link is useless, it should still be getting permissions.